# Android 12 breaks installation of APK via the Package Manager?

Tags: android, apk, android-package-managers, android-12

I was working on an update for my app, a section of which deals with downloading and installing an APK file.

As long as the previous version were targeting SDK 30 everything worked pretty smoothly. But as soon as I incremented the target and compile SDK to 32 it just started behaving queerly.

​

Here is the code that deals which the package manager and the installation:

```
private fun installOnClickListener() {
    binding.termuxInstallCard.showProgress()
    var session: PackageInstaller.Session? = null
    try {
        val packageInstaller: PackageInstaller =
            requireContext().packageManager.packageInstaller
        val params = PackageInstaller.SessionParams(
            PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL
        )
        val sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(params)
        session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId)
        viewModel.addApkToSession(session)

        var installBroadcast: PendingIntent? = null
        val intent =
            Intent(PACKAGE_INSTALLED_ACTION).putExtra(
                "packageName",
                "com.termux"
            )

        installBroadcast = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                0,
                intent,
                FLAG_MUTABLE
            )
        } else {
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        }
        session.commit(installBroadcast.intentSender)
        session.close()

    } catch (e: IOException) {
        throw RuntimeException("Couldn't install package", e)
    } catch (e: RuntimeException) {
        session?.abandon()
        throw e
    } finally {
        session?.close()
    }

}
```

Here is what is happening:

​

As I am targeting SDK 32, I am required to specify the **Mutability of PendingIntent**

```
           Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent
```

When I use:

1. FLAG_MUTABLE- The installation just fails stating the error code- STATUS_FAILURE_INVALID with no extra message for debugging in EXTRA_STATUS_MESSAGE. The thing is that when I try to install the same downloaded APK via the adb shell, it just installs normally without any issues.
2. FLAG_IMMUTABLE- The installation succeeds without prompting user with the installation dialog **but nothing is actually installed.**

​

More code in case you need it-

```
fun addApkToInstallSession(
        path: String,
        session: PackageInstaller.Session
    ) {
        val file = File("${context.filesDir.path}/$path")
        val packageInSession: OutputStream = session.openWrite("com.termux", 0, -1)
        val inputStream = FileInputStream(file)
        val byteStream = inputStream.read()
        try {
            var c: Int
            val buffer = ByteArray(16384)
            while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { c = it } >= 0) {
                packageInSession.write(buffer, 0, c)
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            println("IOEX")
        } finally {
            try {
                packageInSession.close()
                inputStream.close()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                println("IOEX in closing the stream")
            }
        }
    }
```

​

```
private val broadcastReceiverForInstallEvents = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val extras = intent.extras
                val status = extras!!.getInt(PackageInstaller.EXTRA_STATUS)
                val packageName = extras.getString("packageName")!!
                if (PACKAGE_INSTALLED_ACTION == intent.action) {
                    println("STATUS $status")
                    when (status) {
                        PackageInstaller.STATUS_PENDING_USER_ACTION -> {
                            try {
                                val confirmIntent = extras[Intent.EXTRA_INTENT] as Intent
                                confirmIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                                context.startActivity(confirmIntent)
                            } catch (e: Exception) {
                                lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                        requireContext(),
                                        "We could not find an application to handle the installation of apps. Please download a package installer.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                    ).show()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        PackageInstaller.STATUS_SUCCESS -> {
                            lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                                println("$packageName Install succeeded!")
                                // todo all done animation

                                binding.termuxInstallCard.markAsComplete()

                                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "All Done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show()

                                lifecycleScope.launch {
                                    // viewModel.setTermuxSetupDone()
                                }
                                /* redirecting... */
                                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                                    redirect()
                                }, 2000)

                            }
                        }
                        PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE, PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE_ABORTED, PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE_BLOCKED, PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE_CONFLICT, PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE_INCOMPATIBLE, PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE_INVALID, PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE_STORAGE -> {
                            lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                                println("Extra Status Message${extras.getString("EXTRA_STATUS_MESSAGE")}")
                                "There was an error installing Termux. Please retry.".showSnackbar(
                                    binding.root,
                                    true
                                )
                                binding.termuxInstallCard.hideProgress()
                            }
                        }
                        else -> {
                            lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                                println("$packageName Install failed else!")
                                //  exitActivity("Package failed to install -> Unknown Error!") 
                                binding.termuxInstallCard.hideProgress()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I would really appreciate some help!

​

Comment: AFAIK SDK 30 means Android 10. If it fails in 12 you should check how it behaves in 11 as well. A lot of access rules were changed from Android 10 to 11, they might be the reason why you are failing the installation process. Also you can try calling the package installer and install the package from there. If you need code for that let me know I'll post it since it will be pasted badly in comment

Comment: @DanBaruch As I wrote 31 and beyond causes this issue since it mandates us to specify the mutability of the pending intent. 

Also, I did not understand the second part of the answer. I think I could understand better with some code, we you can provide it.

Comment: Ah I failed to see the 31+ in the exception message. In that case, I'd try to copy the APK file, if possible, to a directory you have access to, such as the public directories on your phone's storage (not on the SD), might help resolve the problem (try both  with MUTUABLE and IMMUTUABLE flags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On calculating the hash of the file I was committing to the session of the Package Manager, I found out that it didn't write the APK file correctly.

```
val inputStream: InputStream = session.openRead("com.termux")

        val file = File("${requireContext().filesDir.path}/test2.apk")
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile()
        }
        try {
            inputStream.use { input ->
                file.outputStream().use { output ->
                    input.copyTo(output)
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("Exception occured $e")
        }
        if (file.length() > 0) {
            val hash = file.getMD5Hash()
            println("HASH of session - $hash")
        }
```

Fixed that and with the combination of the Mutable pending intent. The package is now installing perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

In the past when I tried to install APKs I used either Knox on Samsung devices or I'd refer the user to install the package via package manager, this is the code I've used:

```
public static void cleanInstall(String datum, Context context) {
        File file = new File(datum);

        if (file.exists()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            String type = "application/vnd.android.package-archive";

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                Uri downloadedApk = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, ".MyPackage.myFileProvider", file);
                intent.setDataAndType(downloadedApk, type);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            } else {
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            }

            context.startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "ّFile not found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

I've not used this code in a while so I don't know if it works anymore but it's something you might want to check, to see if it does. Make sure the path you are referring to does not reside on SD as you'll probably face permission denied issues.

Comment: I am afraid that this will not work for any recent android versions since we now have to use package manager to create a session, write the APK to it and commit it to install. Though I have fixed the bug. Thank you : )